# Error uploading App: Alert - One of your apps needs attention

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have this message in my applications dashboard

[image]

For many days I´ve been trying to upload my app to Play Store but they rejected my app twice. They told me that they dont found main function of my app. The 2 times that I´ve received a mail was like this:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

The first time that they rejected my app I just change permissions like they want. They also reject my app anyways.

Now is the third time that I summit the app **I know that Play Console spends hours checking apps** but after summit my app by third attempt in console appear directly *"App rejected"* instead of *"pending of publish"*:

[image]

Now my cuestion is: **¿there is a limit of rejections to get banned?**

Permissions in Manifests:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I´ll appretiate any help.

Comment: can you please provide me what kind of permission your are using in android manifest ?

Comment: I updated the question. There are the permissions.

Comment: as per your permission you define SEND_SMS permission that will categories in google permission document so you have  to remove that application of fill google application define your application core requirement so if google are fine with that of then find without this permission your app will not work so they are allowed this application on play store.https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/

Comment: Problem Solved or not @weirzetig29

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati Due to my clients requirements is nessesary to send SMS, so I really need to use SEND_SMS.

Comment: Can you please share me requirement so i can tell you another way to do it.

Comment: if your client have requirement required SEND_SMS permission then you have to fill google permission declaration form if they allow then or then you can publish apk over google play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your app requires login then please provide a login credential so that Google can do the login and check the main functionality this is the main reason behind app rejection from Google's side.

Comment: Interesting, but now when I´m trying to submit a new version they don´t check the app, just appear _"App rejected"_

Comment: try uploading the application with a different application ID once if it works fine then you need to contact to the Google Play store team for the issue. sometimes if there are multiple rejections then the app got auto-rejected for some time.

Comment: refer below link for more details https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2477981?hl=en

Comment: Do you reffer to upload the app as a new application?